# Python libinsane to Executable file (Where to keep dll file after making exe)

Tags: python-3.x, twain, pyinsane

I followed [this link](https://doc.openpaper.work/libinsane/latest/libinsane/install.html) and [this official git repo of libinsane](https://gitlab.gnome.org/World/OpenPaperwork/libinsane), and setup libinsane in MSYS2 environment. I was even able to scan with scan.py file place in [this folder](https://gitlab.gnome.org/World/OpenPaperwork/libinsane/-/tree/master/subprojects/libinsane-gobject/examples). I have use of pretty much what scan.py is doing in my application. Can you guys suggest how I can club my project. if it is difficult to do how can I make exe of scan.py and use it as standalone application which can be invoked from my application and it will save the jpg file somewhere in the folder where my application can get it from?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are two programs that do something similar and that you can use as reference if you want.

There is a Python test program called [IronScanner](https://openpaper.work/scannerdb/#contribute). It's built as an EXE for Windows, so you can have a look at how it's done (basically, it uses Cx_Freeze):

- [.gitlab-ci.yml](https://gitlab.gnome.org/World/OpenPaperwork/ironscanner/-/blob/ac0708579a71dd2218925ca8429c420df75df1fe/.gitlab-ci.yml#L73)
- [make windows_exe](https://gitlab.gnome.org/World/OpenPaperwork/ironscanner/-/blob/ac0708579a71dd2218925ca8429c420df75df1fe/Makefile#L62)
- [setup_cx_freeze.py](https://gitlab.gnome.org/World/OpenPaperwork/ironscanner/-/blob/ac0708579a71dd2218925ca8429c420df75df1fe/setup_cx_freeze.py)

The same thing goes for [Paperwork](https://openpaper.work/):

- [.gitlab-ci.yml](https://gitlab.gnome.org/World/OpenPaperwork/paperwork/-/blob/c853c13b3addd0260ab0a141dc9d374f84df5ab4/.gitlab-ci.yml#L149)
- [make windows_exe](https://gitlab.gnome.org/World/OpenPaperwork/paperwork/-/blob/c853c13b3addd0260ab0a141dc9d374f84df5ab4/paperwork-gtk/Makefile#L39)
- [setup.py](https://gitlab.gnome.org/World/OpenPaperwork/paperwork/-/blob/c853c13b3addd0260ab0a141dc9d374f84df5ab4/paperwork-gtk/setup.py#L12)